# Adobe Reader 9.5.5 unable to Print Pdf afte upgrading to ubuntu 15.04

Tags: printing, pdf, 15.04, adobe-reader

I've upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04. Now my Adobe Reader 9.5.5 won't print pdf. qpdfview is working fine but I need Adobe Reader 9.5.5 to print booklets. The printing status shows Processing but doesn't print.

[image: A]

Comment: Hi, how is this going?

Comment: I've downgraded to 14.04. So not sure about 15.04